# Any reason I can't AND two or more tags?

Tags: ansible

We have dozens of Ansible roles with tasks which have been tagged with pretty standard labels along with other labels which are broadly in line with the facility or function the task affects.

```
deploy
configure
restart
dependancies
```

```
hubspot
database
nginx
rabbitmq
```

Based on the `--limit` syntax I really wish to do things like `--tags '(hubspot,nginx)&restart'`.

The `--limit` sytnax has [Common patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns) and over time it has proved very useful.

Any reason we cant we have the same for tags?
Or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: "Any reason we cant we have the same for tags?" Because Ansible apparently hasn't implemented that capability. For "why is it designed this way?" questions, your best bet is to contact the developer community; that's not really something we can answer.

Comment: "_your best bet is to contact the developer community_", you could even try to get in touch with them directly and in person on next weekend @[Ansible Stand on FOSDEM 2023](https://fosdem.org/2023/news/2022-12-08-accepted-stands-fosdem-2023/).

Comment: (This might be considered opinion based) I have found from experience that hard tagging tasks individually in general and inside roles in particular brings many more problems (hard maintenance, harder reusability...) than it is trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks U880D, as it happens I will be at FOSDEM and I will talk to them.

Comment: I've made the same observation as others according a former given comment "_... found from experience that hard tagging tasks individually in general and inside roles in particular brings many more problems (hard maintenance, harder reusability...) than it is trying to solve._". By structuring the inventory appropriate, implementing the roles etc. very well structured, in my environment there is no need for `tags` at all. However, they are implemented and used for debugging, testing, kind of ad-hoc task functionality, but there is no dependence for limits, patterns, regex, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

> *Any reason we cant we have the same for tags?*

According the documentation about [Selecting or skipping tags when you run a playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html#selecting-or-skipping-tags-when-you-run-a-playbook) it is just implemented in that documented way and [without patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html#using-patterns).

**Issue Links**

... considerations, discussions, workarounds, etc.

- [Ansible Issue #11185 - Add a feature to run only tasks that have **all** of the given tags](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11185)
- [Ansible Issue #11396 - Feature request: Provide capability to combine tags using logic AND or OR conditions](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11396)
- [Ansible Issue #16273 - Feature request: More flexible tags](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16273)
- [Ansible Issue #18401 - Support patterns logic for tags](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18401)
- [Ansible Issue #31971 - Restrict task execution by tag intersection](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31971)
- [Ansible Issue #70036 - Allow regex for "tags"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/70036)
- [Ansible Pull #70043 - Support simple (fnmatch) wildcarding for tags](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/70043)
- [Ansible Issue #71733 - Allow combining tags with AND](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71733)
- [Ansible Proposal #88 - Wildcards/regex in Ansible tags](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/88)

Comment: Hmmm, interesting; based on my own resaerch and your answer it looks a though the main issue is finding somebody to impliment the feature. However I suspect most of the code is already there within the --limit functionality.

Howeverthe existing "special" tags do provide anything like an AND function. Also the various work arounds are IMHO madness.